# terminator open split windows via bash script

Tags: bash, terminator

Is there a way to open terminator from a bash script and auto split it out into multiple windows, each showing a different command being running?

*(In this case i need it to open 4 split panels/windows each with commands watching & compiling so each will constantly be running)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up [termssh](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/termssh) its on my github projects. You may need to tweak it

Comment: Thanks @vahid, your script is really nice and will serve as a great example for what i need! *Heres a link incase anyone finds this post: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/termssh*

Comment: no worries Stilliard, there is a few things you may wish to play with : querymethod="nc"; - change this to another of the supported methods such as ping or and also enable debug DEBUG=1; to see what is going on to help out with automated connections if you attempt pattern matching a connection